# Can registered users create more users in a django app?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create an app in which a user (not admin) can add more users?
Let me explain a little bit...
If I log in the app as a user I would like to add clients without the intervention of the clients. Also such clients should be able to log in the app and see the information that I placed in their behalf, for instance their orders.

I thought that maybe they can log with their email and drivers license number as password or something like that, information that would be provided at the time of me adding them (a client) to the system